# How can I color text in Perl's standard output?

Tags: perl

How do I color text in Perl's standard output without using any extra module?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense: what are you using to display the text?

Comment: You do it the same way that the modules do. Even if you don't want the modules, you can look at the source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use [`Term::ANSIColor`](http://p3rl.org/Term::ANSIColor).

Comment: Or just [copy its source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RRA/ANSIColor-3.00/ANSIColor.pm)

Comment: Although copying its source code it topologically the same as installing it. :)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code to know which control sequences to output if you do not want to use any module.